# Can I override the root font size for the CSS rem units for subcomponents?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I use the components of a design system (Semantic UI React). Everything is measured with rem and the font-size for the html tag (the root) is 14 px.

Now I want to introduce a new design system (Tailwind UI). Which also uses rem everywhere and is based on a root font-size of 16px. So when I insert new components, they are too small.

So: Is there a way to have a separate root font size for certain areas?

Answer (score 0):

You may use :

```
html { font-size : px;}
```

If you want different root values you may edit them in the pages you want editing the CSS of every page to have a custom root font-size in the html tag, hope it works :D gl

Answer (score 0):

Root font size is inherently global, you'd need to override it on a case-by-case basis once changing your root size.

```
<style>
  html { font-size: 16px; }
  .override { font-size: 14px; }
</style>
```